# Unable to get Linkedin auth to work with django-social-auth

Tags: django, authentication, linkedin-api

I am trying to configure Linkedin auth on my Django website. I use [django-social-auth](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#) I follow the steps mentioned in the [Docs](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html). I have been stuck on this for quite some time.

```
My settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin',
'social_auth',

'mytests'
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'social_auth.backends.contrib.linkedin.LinkedinBackend',
                            'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('linkedin',)

LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY        = 'py5pspq52ypesv' #API Key
LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET     = 'OyzsrC5GqIo85z9GsWc' #Secret Key

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'checkbox'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login-error/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
```

And in my Template

```
<a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'linkedin' %}">linkedin</a>
```

I get Error

```
Error!
  Sorry but some error made you impossible to login.

  Please try again Home
```

Comment: Do you also get an error like "Bad request" ?

Comment: @Erman No i did not get a "Bad Request"

Comment: I know this question is old but if you are still using this LinkedIn app you might want to change your secret key since you exposed it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the settings i used for Linkedin Auth

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email'
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login_error/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'social_auth.backends.contrib.linkedin.LinkedinBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

The SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS, SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME are not required
```

Comment: Hey Rakesh i  made login ,NOw how can i store basic information in my database

Comment: please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

You should try testing on the same domain as application is configured.

Register API KEY for domain like test123.youworkserevr.com and put in you hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       test123.youworkserevr.com
```

Try access for you app via test123.youworkserevr.com (instead of 127.0.0.1 or localhost)