# Django "linked-in authorization token not found"

Tags: django, python-2.7, linkedin-api

This is my first time using the LinkedIn API. I am using Django.

I have added django allauth from github to my project.

In settings.py i have added linkedin to "INSTALLED APPS"

I have created an application in Linkedin api
Then i added the user access key and secret key into my admin phase.

> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = (
> 'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.sites',
> 'django.contrib.messages',
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
> 'django.contrib.admin',
> 'registration',
> 'django.contrib.humanize',
> 'allauth',
> 'allauth.account',
> 'allauth.socialaccount',
> 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
> 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
> 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin', )
> ```

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/Dashboard/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/accounts/login_error/'
```

> ```
> TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
> 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',    
> "django.core.context_processors.debug",
> "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
> "django.core.context_processors.media",
> "django.core.context_processors.static",
> "django.core.context_processors.request",
> "django.core.context_processors.tz",
> "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
> "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
> "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",)
>
> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
> 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',    
> "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
> ```
>
> )

urls.py

```
url(r'', include('allauth.urls')),
```

And in my Template

```
<a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'linkedin' %}">linkedin</a>
```

When i try to login through linked-in, my url ir redirected to **"/accounts/profile"** I get the error ***"We were unable to find the authorization token."***

Anyone have any insight as to why I can't get the access token PIN?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some code to what you have tried?

Comment: I am not sure about what code u are asking?

Comment: How are you calling the LinkedIn API for example. Have you been issued a token from the linkedin? Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853038/unable-to-get-linkedin-auth-to-work-with-django-social-auth?rq=1 ?